# Minecraft scoreboard criteria of damage dealt absorbed not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, i set up the scoreboard with criteria `minecraft.custom:minecraft.damage_dealt_absorbed` and set it to my sidebar. Then, I hit my friend that have absorption effect active on him. I expected the score to go up but nothing actually happens. Is it a bug or did I do something wrong? Besides, how can I detect when a player with absorption effect takes damage.

Comment: Which game are you playing, MCJava, MCBE, MCCE, …?

Comment: im playing java edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does appear that this is [due to a bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-141826).

I don't know if there's an alternative, but it may be possible to run a function, when a player takes any kind of damage, and then check if the player has absorbtion.

Comment: but the things is as long as the player has an absroption effect, the game does not count the player receives any damage.